# How to convert XSD file to XLS

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

I have a XSD file and I need to convert that to MS Excel file.
The XSD is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="shiporder">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="shipto">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="orderid" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Pls help me, I really don't know how and where to start.

Comment: What data do you expect to see in the Excel file ? Excel supports multiple file formats. Easiest is to create a CSV file and load it in Excel.

Comment: Your question isn't all that clear. Do you want to convert the XSD into Excel? The first answer suggests that you want to use an XSD to import XML data into Excel?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This answer is equally for you as well as @Alex, @Michael and @forty-two. I am illustrating it using Excel 2010, so if you're on another version, I'll leave it up to you to make the necessary adjustments.

First thing, make sure the developer tab shows (Click the File tab, Options).

[image: Excel 2010 options for Developer tab]

You now have to create an XML source from your XSD: click the Developer tab; in the XML group, toggle Source button to show the Xml Source task pane; then click the XML Maps button.

[image: Excel showing key UI elements for creating an XML map]

Click Add button at the prompt; point to the XSD file; then click OK to go back to the main screen.

[image: Excel showing XSD loaded in an XML map]

Then you can drag and drop your shipOrder to a cell in a worksheet, to anchor the generated mapped table.

[image: Excel showing mapped XSD]

Next, you may use Import to get your XML data into the spreadsheet, and Export to get it out. There are a couple of additional things to pay attention to; read [this article on Microsoft's site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/export-xml-data-HP010206401.aspx); pay particular attention to the issues with exporting XML data (error XML maps in my workbook are not exportable). This is because of the 1 to many cardinality between shiporder and item. You can try to handle it using mapped ranges - I'll leave this all up to you. The best would be for you to read the online help for the XML developer section...

Answer (score 6):

Go to `MS Excel` -> `File` -> `Open`. Select the xsd file.

You will be prompted on how you would like to open the file. You can select the option 'As an XML table'. Save the file in excel format.

Comment: So simple and yet so effective!

Comment: This is a great way to see the xml data in a tabular format.

Comment: Thank you for the method. BTW, you can `drag and drop` the file directly into Excel (didn't know if versions matter tho...)

Answer (score 0):

You could save the file as an XML file and then open it in Excel and open as a 'Read-only workbook' when prompted. However it won't be in a nice format, but at least all the data (along with the XML paths as columns) will be there.

You can then edit the data as you require. Anything else will require some processing.

Comment: The above is XSD file, I don't know how to convert it to XML also. If I open that in MS-Excel, its gives nothing. Empty page.

Comment: Just save the file with the .xml extension then open it in excel. Both file types have very similar structures.

Comment: XSD **is** XML! It's even declared as such at the beginning.

Answer (score -3):

Select the whole text of the XSD in a text editor, copy it to the clipboard, click on a cell in an Excel spreadsheet, and do a Paste. Your XSD data will now be in your spreadsheet.

It won't be in a very useful format, but you haven't told us what you want the spreadsheet to look like, and I find it hard to imagine a format that *would* be useful.

Comment: No, even this didn't work :(, It pasted the whole XSD file in the cell. But I need it to be converted to table format.

Comment: Sorry you missed the irony in my answer. I did point out that the result wouldn't be very useful, even though it satisfies the requirements as stated. My hidden message was that you need to specify the expected output much more clearly.